# Getting Felix/OSGI bundles from Maven repo at runtime

Tags: maven, osgi, bundle

I have been searching for any possible way for a Felix instance to pull bundle artifacts from a Maven repository when it starts up. I have Google'd this but always end up with search results for Maven's BND plugin (which I'm currently using to create and install the bundles at compile time).

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Essentially, I'd like to define some kind of Felix configuration that specifies exactly what bundles to pull and from where to negate the manual step of downloading the artifacts and placing them inside Felix's 'bundle' directory.

EDIT
I should also mention that the development machine is completely separate from the AWS VM hosting Felix. This is why I need Felix/plugin to download the artifacts itself instead of making this part of the build step.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [PaxRunner](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxrunner/Pax+Runner) as a provisioning OSGi tool. It resolves and downloads bundles you defined and includes into Felix/Equinox/... bundles start list.